# I cannot add an account in Windows 10 Calendar app

Tags: windows-10, google-calendar, windows-10-calendar-app

In Windows 10 Calendar app, I wanted to add Google Calendar account.

I went to Setting (*of the Calendar app*) → Manage account → Clicked 'Add an account'.

But this 'Add an account' button is not clickable. (*I clicked it, but nothing happened*).

What would be the problem?

Comment: that seems to be a frequent problem. I face the same all of a sudden. There are many tips and tricks pages out there but none of them could help my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your account via the settings app instead.

Settings => Accounts => Email & app accounts => Email, calendar, and contacts => Add an account.